# Yii2 join relations for multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, join, yii2

I am new to yii2. I have read the documentation and some answers on sof but still I cant get to work with relations in yii2. I am able to create raw mysql query for the problem but I dont know how to create the same query using yii2 relations. I am confused with via, joinWith and some key concepts. I will make the problem as descriptive as possible.
I have four models.

```
Category, CategoryNews, NewsTags, Tags

category table - cat_id, cat_name
news_category table - nc_id, nc_cat_id, nc_news_id
news_tags table - nt_id, nt_news_id, nt_tag_id
tags table - tag_id, tag_name
```

What I need is tags model object for each category, that is for each category i need all news tags belonging to that category. Request is from gridview.
The generated relations are:

```
Category Model:

public function getNewsCategory()
{
    return $this->hasMany(NewsCategory::className(), ['nc_cat_id' => 'cat_id']);
}

NewsCategory Model:

public function getNcNews()
{
    return $this->hasOne(News::className(), ['news_id' => 'nc_news_id']);
}

public function getNcCat()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Category::className(), ['cat_id' => 'nc_cat_id']);
}

NewsTags Model:

public function getNtNews()
{
    return $this->hasOne(News::className(), ['news_id' => 'nt_news_id']);
}

public function getNtTag()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Tags::className(), ['tag_id' => 'nt_tag_id']);
}

News Model:

public function getNewsCategory()
{
    return $this->hasMany(NewsCategory::className(), ['nc_news_id' => 'news_id']);
}

public function getNewsTags()
{
    return $this->hasMany(NewsTags::className(), ['nt_news_id' => 'news_id']);
}

Tags Model:

public function getNewsTags()
{
    return $this->hasMany(NewsTags::className(), ['nt_tag_id' => 'tag_id']);
}
```

ie. each category contains multiple news and each news contain mutiple tags and I need all tags related to each category.
More precisely, on the gridview I need all categories and a column displaying all tags related to these categories.
Please help!!

Answer (score 4):

You can avoid declaration of models for junction tables, using [`viaTable`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#junction-table) syntax for `many-to-many` relations. Then your code will contain only three models (`Category`, `News` and `Tag`) and everything will be much simplier.

Your code for AR models and relations could looks as follows:

```
public class Category extends ActiveRecord 
{
    public function getNews()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(News::className(), ['id' => 'news_id'])
            ->viaTable('news_category_table', ['category_id' => 'id']);
    }
}

public class News extends ActiveRecord 
{
    public function getCategories()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Category::className(), ['id' => 'category_id'])
            ->viaTable('news_category_table', ['news_id' => 'id']);
    }

    public function getTags()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Tags::className(), ['id' => 'tag_id'])
            ->viaTable('news_tags_table', ['news_id' => 'id']);
    }
}

public class Tag extends ActiveRecord 
{
    public function getNews()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(News::className(), ['id' => 'news_id'])
            ->viaTable('news_tags_table', ['tag_id' => 'id']);
    }
}
```

These relations you can use in [`link`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html#link()-detail) and [`unlink`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html#unlink()-detail) functions (rows in junction tables will be managed by Yii in backround). But keep in mind that you should use `TRUE` as second param in `unlink()` to remove row in junction table:

```
$article = new News();
$tag = new Tag();    
$tag->save();
$article->link('tags', $tag);
$article->link('caterories', $category);
```

OR vice versa

```
$tag->link('news', $article);
$category->link('news', $article);
```

To get all tags in given category you can declare following function in `Category` class:

```
public function getTags()
{
    return Tags::find()
        ->joinWith(['news', 'news.categories C'])
        ->where(['C.id' => $this->id])
        ->distinct();
}
```

This will work as relation query and you can use it as `$category->tags` or as `$category->getTags()->count()` or any other way (but not in `link` and `unlink` functions).

P.S. To use provided example in your code You should first change names, because I used singular form for AR classes names (`Tag`) and short notation for primary and foreign keys (`id`, `tag_id` etc). And I'd recommend you also to use such naming approach in your code and DB structure.

P.P.S. This example code wasn't tested so be careful :)